# Not getting Client Authority/Role while using RemoteTokenService

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring-Security-OAuth2 for implementing my own oauth server and resource server. I am using `RemoteTokenService` as my `ResourceServerTokenService` on my ResourceServer which will authenticate any accessToken using the `CheckTokenEndpoint` (/oauth/check_token) on OAuth Server.

I have added a antMatcher for an api url e.g. /data/list which will need client application Role / Authority: "**ROLE_ADMIN**" like this `.antMatcher('/data/list').access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`

but it is not working.
I have done some trial and error on this end point and what I get is following :::

When oauth grant is client only i.e. client_credential grant.
what we get from /oauth/check_token

```
{
 "scope":["read"],
 "exp":1412955393,
 "client_id":"sample_test_client_app"
}
```

we dont get any client authority. so how can spring security will perform above authorization check of `"#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"`

When oauth grant is user + client i.e. Authorization_code grant
what we get from /oauth/check_token

```
{
 "aud":["resource_id"],
 "exp":1412957540,
 "user_name":"developer",
 "authorities":["ROLE_USER"],
 "client_id":"sample_test_client_app",
 "scope":["read"]
}
```

and for authorization_code grnat we are still not getting client authority/role. so can any one tell me how can we perform clientHasRole authentication on any api url?

Comment: Looks like it's probably a bug to me. You could provide your own /check_token endpoint to work round it.

Comment: @DaveSyer I think there is a bug in DefaultAccessTokenConverter. So I have to inject my own AccessTokenConverter for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" to work we have to implemented our AccessTokenConverter and inject it into auth server and resource server.

so create a new class which extends `DefaultAccessTokenConverter` and override `convertAccessToken` and `extractAuthentication` methods.

In `convertAccessToken` method just add

```
Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>) super.convertAccessToken(token, authentication);
OAuth2Request clientToken = authentication.getOAuth2Request();
response.put("clientAuthorities", clientToken.getAuthorities());
```

and in `extractAuthentication` method add

```
Collection<HashMap<String, String>> clientAuthorities = (Collection<HashMap<String, String>>) map.get("client_authority");

Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

for (HashMap<String, String> grantedAuthority : clientAuthorities) {
   for (String authority : grantedAuthority.values()) {
       grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
   }
}

Set<String> resourceIds = new LinkedHashSet<String>(map.containsKey(AUD) ? (Collection<String>) map.get(AUD) : Collections.<String> emptySet());
OAuth2Request request = new OAuth2Request(parameters, clientId, grantedAuthorities, true, scope, resourceIds, null, null, null);
```

- At auth server :

  set this class in `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`
- At resource server :

  set this class in `RemoteTokenServices`

Comment: I think it would be better to ensure that the client authorities get mapped to scopes and then just use scope in your resource access decision. It's up to you of course.

Comment: BTW Spring OAuth 2.0.4 has this change (or something equivalent) in the `DefaultAccessTokenConverter`.

Comment: @DaveSyer thanks for the update and your suggestion.